# How to Change Layout with Another Layout Dynamically

Tags: android

I've `main_layout.xml` as a root layout, does not matter it's `RelativeLayout` or `LinearLayout`. And that root layout has different layouts in its own. Basicly it's looking like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/default_background" >

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/panel_bar">
        <!-- -->
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/other_bar">
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_bar">
        <Button id="@+id/change_button" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

When I've clicked to `change_button` I want to change `panel_bar` with another layout, let's say `another_layout`. By the way, `another_layout` is an existing layout in a differet file. They are both (`panel_bar` and `another_layout`) the same height and weight. I just want to switch them.

Maybe my idea is not true, I may need different approach. I'm really inquisitorial about your suggestions. Any help would be great.

Comment: Interesting, maybe put them all in one layout, then in your Java you dynamically set their Visibility.

Comment: I'll have a look at `ViewSwitcher` thank you njzk2. @userIsAMonkey putting all in one layout is a solution but thus situated it's hart to design layouts. Anyway if there is no other answers, I'll try that, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way is just put both layouts in root layout and set `visible` of one to `gone` then switch visibility as you need.